# Google Sheets Script: Using two at a time

Tags: google-sheets

I have managed to get two separate scripts working which hide rows in the specified sheet tab based on a cell value. The problem I am running into is that I seem to only be able to use one or the other rather than have them both work in each separate use case.

After looking online, I think multiple scripts should be able to work as long as they are on the same sheet, but I'm not sure on this. After putting them into the same sheet, I am running into the same situation where either one or the other will work.

Below is the script I am working with which Contains both scripts I'm trying to get running. Is it possible to have more than one script working within a Google Sheets doc?

```
function onEdit(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getSheetByName("TX MD 2017");           
  var row = s.getRange('C2').getValues();                         
s.showRows(1);
for(var i=0; i< row.length; i++){ if(row[i] == 'hide') 
     { s.hideRows(5);
       s.hideRows(7); 
       s.hideRows(9);}

     else if(row[i] == 'unhide'){ s.unhideRow(ss.getDataRange()); } 
}      

s = ss.getSheetByName("DC MD 2017");           
row = s.getRange('C2').getValues();                         

s.showRows(1);
for(var i=0; i< row.length; i++){ if(row[i] == 'hide') 
     { s.hideRows(6);
       s.hideRows(9); 
       s.hideRows(12);}                           
     else if(row[i] == 'unhide'){ s.unhideRow(ss.getDataRange()); } 
                            }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an onEdit function embedded in the onEdit function.  Combine this into one function and you should be good:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getSheetByName("TX MD 2017");           
var row = s.getRange('C2').getValues();                         
s.showRows(1);
for(var i=0; i< row.length; i++){
  if(row[i] == 'hide') {
     s.hideRows(1);
     s.hideRows(2); 
     s.hideRows(6);
     s.hideRows(4);
     s.hideRows(9);
   }                           
 else if(row[i] == 'unhide'){
   s.unhideRow(ss.getDataRange());
 } 
}

//Second section for specified tab 2 

s = ss.getSheetByName("DC MD 2017");
row = s.getRange('C2').getValues();                         

s.showRows(1);
for(var i=0; i< row.length; i++){
  if(row[i] == 'hide') {
   s.hideRows(1);
   s.hideRows(2); 
   s.hideRows(12);
   s.hideRows(11);
   s.hideRows(13);
 }
  else if(row[i] == 'unhide'){
       s.unhideRow(ss.getDataRange());
  } 
 }
}
```

You could create a function for the common portions of the code, to call to hide/unhide the rows, and call that for each tab from inside the onEdit function, or keep it as is since you are hiding different rows.